# Execute transformations on few columns while selecting all columns of a table - Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am dealing with dataframes with around 600+ columns and I want to execute some Spark SQL logic on few of the columns of these dataframes.

Currently I am using **select col1, col2, transformation(col3), transformation(col4), col5, col6... from <SPARK_VIEW>**. I need to write the names of around 600 columns to generate this query and it is also throwing me runtime errors due to such a long query. Is there any better way of achieving this.

Comment: are you trying to solve only in sqls ? or do you have scala code as well to handle this?

Comment: I have Scala code that triggers this spark SQL.